# Different outputs for the same function with different callbacks (Heap's Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, heaps-algorithm

I'm using the Heap's Algorithm and it's working well with the callback function `output` console logging the outcomes. But if I change the action of the callback function `output` to `array.push`, it pushes the same array over and over. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let swap = function (array, index1, index2) {
    var temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;

    return array;
  };

  let permutationHeap = function (array, callback, n) {
    n = n || array.length;
    if (n === 1) {
      callback(array);
    } else {
      for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        permutationHeap(array, callback, n - 1);
        if (n % 2) {
          swap(array, 0, n - 1);
        } else {
          swap(array, i - 1, n - 1);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  let finalResult = [];

  var output = function (input) {
    //console.log(input);
    finalResult.push(input);
  };

  permutationHeap(["Mary", "John", "Denis"], output);
  
  console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is an `Object`, objects are pointers/references.. I used the `spread` operator to kinda clone the input so it doesnt keep doing the reference jitsu

```js
let swap = function (array, index1, index2) {
    var temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;

    return array;
  };

  let permutationHeap = function (array, callback, n) {
    n = n || array.length;
    if (n === 1) {
      callback(array);
    } else {
      for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        permutationHeap(array, callback, n - 1);
        if (n % 2) {
          swap(array, 0, n - 1);
        } else {
          swap(array, i - 1, n - 1);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  let finalResult = [];

  var output = function (input) {
    //console.log(input);
    finalResult.push([...input]); //spread operator >:D
  };

  permutationHeap(["Mary", "John", "Denis"], output);
  
  console.log(finalResult)
```

Comment: One last question after you finish the next episode. On the swap function, when I call `var temp = array[index1]; array[index1] = array[index2]; array[index2] = temp;`, I do not change the object's values for that keys? Even after that, the initial object keeps the same?

Comment: yes.. because `array` itself was edited.. remember objects are references and not copies